# UL align bottom center

Tags: html, css

I am using "margin 0 auto" but the ul is not aligning to the bottom center, I have a div around the ul. what am i doing wrong? Thank you guys

Please check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tnv3q3kb/

## html

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="sideMenu">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mapcontainer">
        
        <div class="map">
            <span>Loading map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menuBottom">
            <ul>
                <li>WEATHER</li>
                <li>HOTELS</li>
                <li>RESTAURANTS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

## css

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.sideMenu {
    float: left;
    background: #222b30;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mapcontainer {
    float: left;
    background: #999;
    width: 80%;
}

.map {
    display: block!important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

div.menuBottom {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

div.menuBottom ul {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.menuBottom ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

div.menuBottom ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `float: left;` on both the surrounding container **and**  the list. Where's your brain today that you are asking why it's not centered??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi now modify your `css` as **like this**

```
.mapcontainer{
    position: relative;
}
div.menuBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
div.menuBottom ul{float: none;
    display: inline-block;}
```

**Demo is**

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.sideMenu {
    float: left;
    background: #222b30;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mapcontainer {
    float: left;
    background: #999;
    width: 80%;
}

.map {
    display: block!important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

div.menuBottom {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

div.menuBottom ul {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.menuBottom ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

div.menuBottom ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}


.mapcontainer{
        position: relative;
    }
    div.menuBottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    div.menuBottom ul{float: none;
        display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    

    <div class="sideMenu">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mapcontainer">
        
        <div class="map">
            <span>Loading map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menuBottom">
            <ul>
                <li>WEATHER</li>
                <li>HOTELS</li>
                <li>RESTAURANTS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to not put `float: left` everywhere.

Secondly, the trick to make the `<ul>` align to the bottom center is to first make the parent `<div>` 100% in width and to make sure `text-align` of that div is set to `center`.

Then the last fix is to set `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` to your `<li>`s to make them appear on the same line instead of each getting a new line.

The forked JSFiddle with the solution can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/hqhq8eg0/

CSS code:

```
div.menuBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.menuBottom ul {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.menuBottom ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.menuBottom ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```